# window Watchdog Timer STM32F4

Tags: c, stm32, watchdog, stm32f4discovery, stm32f4

Edited 
DONE NOW .. I'll reconstruct the code, but now it's done and tested

I need to implement a timer that checks for conditions every x sec .. the problem I face that the program doesn't reset when it enters infinite loop    ( away for check like if the system has been halted) ...
these links helped me .. manual from page 74 http://www2.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/3d/6d/5a/66/b4/99/40/d4/DM00031020.pdf/files/DM00031020.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00031020.pdf ..

and this link http://www.programmershare.com/3518407/
thanks in advance

I currently have this code :

```
#include "stm32f4xx.h"
#include <stm32f4xx_gpio.h>
#include <stm32f4xx_rcc.h>
#include <stm32f4xx_wwdg.h>

void setup_Periph(void);
void Delay(unsigned long ms);


void Delay(unsigned long ms)
{ unsigned long i,j;
for(i=0;i<ms;i++)
    for(j=0;j<1450;j++);
 }


 void setup_Periph(void)
 {

RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOD, ENABLE);

 //port initialization
 GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;

 GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin=GPIO_Pin_0|GPIO_Pin_1;
 GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode=GPIO_Mode_OUT;
 GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed=GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
 GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd=GPIO_PuPd_UP;
 GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType=GPIO_OType_PP;
 GPIO_Init(GPIOD,&GPIO_InitStructure);

 }

 void ResetWatchdog(void)
 { WWDG_SetCounter(80);}

 void WWDG_IRQHandler(void)
 {

 if (WWDG_GetFlagStatus())
  {
   WWDG_SetCounter(0x7f);
   WWDG_ClearFlag();
   }

 }

 void FeedDog(float round)
{
while(round)
   { Delay (65);
    WWDG_SetCounter(127);
    round--;}
 }


 int main(void)
 {
 //RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_WWDG, ENABLE);

 //System Clock auf Watchdog
 RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_WWDG, ENABLE);

 WWDG_SetPrescaler(WWDG_Prescaler_8);    
 //WWDG clock counter = (PCLK1(30MHz)/4096)/1 = 7324 Hz (~137 us)

 WWDG_SetCounter(80);           //Werte 0x40 und 0x7F
 WWDG_SetWindowValue(80);         //0x80

                //Reset  < 120  > 64

 WWDG_Enable(127);            //WWDG timeout = ~137 us * (127-64) = 8.6ms

 WWDG_ClearFlag();
 WWDG_EnableIT();

 setup_Periph();
 //make sure the clk is stable
   RCC_HSEConfig(RCC_HSE_ON);
   while(!RCC_WaitForHSEStartUp());


 GPIO_SetBits(GPIOD, GPIO_Pin_1);
 Delay(10000); //10 ms
 GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOD, GPIO_Pin_1);
 Delay(10000); //100 ms

  while (1)
  {

          GPIO_SetBits(GPIOD, GPIO_Pin_0);
            Delay(10000); //10 ms

            GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOD, GPIO_Pin_0);
            Delay(10000); //100 ms

            void ResetWatchdog(void);
            WWDG_SetCounter(80);
        FeedDog(8);
            for(;;) {}

      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several things very obviously wrong here. Most troubling among them are:

1. Your `Delayms()` function does not implement any kind of delay. It appears to configure one of the LEDs to flash.
2. You are never calling `InitWatchdog()`. (Instead, you are declaring its prototype within `main()` for some reason.)

I don't want this to sound too harsh, but: do you know C? This code reads as though it's been put together by copying and pasting pieces from examples without understanding them. If you do not know C, attempting to develop software for an embedded system is not an effective way to learn it, especially without guidance.

Comment: yes, you are right um just a beginner ... your notes helped me a lot ... I actually edit  as if someone else see the code can skip these katastrofi mistakes ... in fact I have a task so I learn and develop in // . I have no choice right now ... but I'll ..promise isAllah